# Not able to fetch .env urls to my component on my react project

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I am using 3 .env file like .env.prod, .env.dev and .env. But not able to fetch the url to my component.

I am using react 16.9.

Can you please help me why I am not able to fetch it?

in my .env / .env.dev files

`loginUrl = = "http://localhost:8080/api/2.0/admin/auth/login"`

in my package.json files

````
 "scripts": {
    "start": "cp ./.env.dev .env && react-scripts start",
    "build:dev": "cp ./.env.dev .env && react-scripts build",
    "build:stage": "cp ./.env.stage .env && react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "cp ./.env.prod .env && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },```

Inside my component, when I am printing it it is giving undefined.

console.log(process.env.loginUrl) is giving undefined
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using react-script

Looking at [react script adding-custom-environment-variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) documentation, variables are automatically loaded from `.env` if:

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

Seams like the problem come from the name of your variable, try renaming in `REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL`

> *Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@0.5.0 and higher.*

## If using Webpack instead of react-script

You need to use [webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to inject environments variables in your code.

In your `webpack.config.js` file :

```
require("dotenv").config(); // will load .env file in process.env
const webpack = require("webpack");
...

plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
        SENTRY_DSN: JSON.stringify(process.env.SENTRY_DSN),
        BUILD_DATE: JSON.stringify(new Date()),
        TRAVIS_COMMIT: JSON.stringify(process.env.TRAVIS_COMMIT)
      }
    }),
   ...
]
```

Make sure you have strings only as if the value isn't a string, it will be stringified (including functions).

Then in your code, you can call `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`

Comment: Is there any solution not using webpack?

Comment: Oups, didn't know `react-script` does not expose webpack config . I check the documentation and updated my answer , should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. The only problem was, I was not adding REACT_APP_ to my variables inside .env file. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Sir I don't have 15 rep. So I am not able to give upvote. But thanks for the answer. Happy coding

Comment: No worry for the upvote, what you actually can do is select the answer as accepted to rewards posters, informs others that your issue is resolved, and pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first. [(more details here)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).